# Flexbox item's height is affecting the width of another item

Tags: css, flexbox

So this issue is making me scratch my head. I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ss439dec/) where the code works exactly how I expected it to.

But I have similar if not the same code implemented [here](http://www.stepyouraimup.com/blog/hello-test/#comment-2), and you'll see because I have more text it's causing the first flex-item's width to adjust itself.

I'm still new to flexbox, but I've been doing a bunch of reading on them, maybe I got something wrong in the css? I don't see how since the fiddle works but the real example doesn't.

CSS

```
.comment-meta-body {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.comment-meta-text {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

**EDIT**
flex-basis of 70px seems to make it work, but I still don't understand what's happening with the live example, in the fiddle I've tried setting a width to the parent container trying to replicate it but I can't. The fiddle works perfect. Doing some more testing, in the live example, if I set a max-width on the

tag that's less than the width of the container, by let's say 100px, it looks fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web you have this css for the images:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

In the *fiddle* you haven't and the image uses its original size.

Comment: But the container the img is in has a defined width and height, does that not take affect?

Comment: the images are bit diferents than others element, although the size is not defined, they have a size. To overwrite this size you have to set in the css. Sorry my English, you understand?

Comment: do you mean set the width and height of the img itself from css? Hmm, doesn't sound very fluid.

Comment: Look whats happend in your example http://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/ss439dec/3/  I only put a border to distinguish the container and the image, the image has its size, if you want it fit to the parent, you have to set image size to width:100%